# Compare two different string with the same part in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url

I need to accept URL and compare it with another. Both URL's have the same start but different end which dynamically changes. I accept something like this `https://url.com/something_else` and need to compare with `https://url.com/` check if this part is in received URL without `something_else`. How can I do this in Rails?

Comment: `url.start_with?("https://url.com/")`

Comment: For two arbitrary strings, you can use a regular expression or some method like `start_with?` - as above. But these are no ordinary strings; these are URIs. Presumably, you want things like `http://url.com`, `www.url.com`, `https://www.url.com`, `url.com/`, .... to be considered equivalent. And doing this reliably with regex would be very hard (not to mention you're re-inventing the wheel!) Therefore, as answered below, I would suggest using the standard library's `URI` module.

Comment: Your question has no code which makes it difficult for others to understand what you're doing and how you're going about it. Please update your post with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a **clear problem statement**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use URI module https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/URI.html

```
uri = URI("http://foo.com/posts?id=30&limit=5#time=1305298413")
uri.host
#=> "foo.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the URI Module as given below:-

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI("http://foo.com/posts?id=30&limit=5#time=1305298413")
#=> #<URI::HTTP:0x00000000b14880
      URL:http://foo.com/posts?id=30&limit=5#time=1305298413>
uri.scheme
#=> "http"
uri.host
#=> "foo.com"
uri.path
#=> "/posts"
uri.query
#=> "id=30&limit=5"
uri.fragment
#=> "time=1305298413"

uri.to_s
#=> "http://foo.com/posts?id=30&limit=5#time=1305298413"
```

Thanks :)